# Downloading HLS videos(m3u8 videos) along with streaming in ios to make a feed list like facebook with caching

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to cache at least the 10 last watched videos.

I am using 2 viewcontrollers :

1. One for the feed with an inlined feeds which has a tableview in which all cells have a AVPlayer layer and the cell that is in center I am loading the AVPLayer in that layer to play the asset that belongs to that cell.
2. Other one is AVPlayerviewcontroller which is opened when user clicks on the cell to show the asset in full screen.

Currently the goal is to avoid rebuffering the same HLS stream when the clicking on the inline player to expand it.

**Approches tried:**

1. I have tried with the HLS catalog sample provided by apple in following link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html. But the code fails several times to download the video without proper reason for failure and the video in the table do not play then on-words.
2. I have also looked out for samples where this can be achieved using HTTP Proxy server in ios but did not find any working sample that can be integrated to achieve the requirement.

Following are the links I have gone through for  HTTP Proxy server method :-

- https://github.com/yangchao0033/HLS-Demo
- https://github.com/kencool/KSHLSPlayer